# Read URL from web browser in Python

Tags: python, url

I open a web browser with 2 tabs, e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) by hand.

The programm should find which web browser is open and which URL has the TABs in the web browser)

I read active processes in Windows but there was no information from URL

Comment: Why read the browser process instead of using Selenium to open the browser **with** those sites in tabs?

Comment: The two URLs were just an example.
Depending on my interest, I open different tabbs and then I want to read the URL from all tabs and save the URL as a TXT file.

Comment: Like I said, though, you can [use Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) to automate your browser without having it already opened.

Comment: That means with the Selenium module I can recognize the open browser and read the two URLs from tabs?